# More efficient way to draw lines on canvas?

Tags: android

I'm drawing a grid over a bitmap.  The user can change the size, aspect ratio, or drag the grid around.  Doing so with drawLines causes fairly bad stuttering when these operations occur.  Is there a better approach?

```
 private void drawGrid()
{
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    gridOverlayView.invalidate();

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numColumns +1 ; i++)
    {
        points[count]   = originX + (cellWidth * i);
        points[count+1] = originY;
        points[count+2] = originX + (cellWidth * i);
        points[count+3] = originY + (gridHeight);
        count += 4;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numRows +1; i++)
    {
        points[count]   = originX;
        points[count+1] = originY + (cellHeight * i);
        points[count+2] = originX + (gridWidth);
        points[count+3] = originY + (cellHeight * i);
        count += 4;
    }

    canvas.drawLines(points, 0, points.length, paint);
    gridOverlayView.setImageBitmap(gridOverlayBitmap);
}
```

this is being called from:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        originX += e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        if(originX < 0f)
        {
            originX = 0f;
        }
        if(originX + gridWidth > imageWidth)
        {
            originX = imageWidth - gridWidth;
        }

        originY += e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if(originY < 0f)
        {
            originY = 0f;
        }
        if(originY + gridHeight > imageHeight)
        {
            originY = imageHeight - gridHeight;
        }

        drawGrid();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing a couple things: Optimizing the layout following the [dev guide](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html). Then I simply scaled down the bitmap I was using to draw the grid, then scaled it back up when I wanted to save it onto the original image.  That got everything moving nice and smoothly... (actually too fast)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no source code you're calling that function, I cannot find the exact reason of stuttering. I guess you want to change the grids in 'real-time' with user interaction.

I think you should avoid redrawing the entire grid while user is dragging.
Instead, you can translate, scale or rotate(if you need) the previous Bitmap as you wish.

Of course the result image will sometimes not in a good quality, but you can recreate the whole grid bitmap when the user stops interacting.
By this way you can achieve 'real-time-like' grid creating effect.